# Export variable in Makefile

Tags: makefile

Having problem in exporting a variable in my makefile. I have `Makefile.mk` in `/home/user/sarwan/DMAgent` directory.

There I have following statement:

```
export VZW_BASE_DIR=$(PWD)
```

Then I have another makefile in `/home/user/sarwan/DMAgent/agent` directory which contains:

```
include ../Makefile.mk
export VZW_BASE_DIR
```

Problem is I expect `VZW_BASE_DIR` to be `/home/user/sarwan/DMAgent` but rather its taking as
`/home/user/sarwan/DMAgent/agent`.

How can I write so that it works as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PWD` gives you your current working directory, not the directory the currently included file is in. Even when including a file in a totally different directory, your working directory stays the same.

Since you're *already* hard-coding relative paths (see the `include` statement), I see no issue with continuing to do so for other reasons. First, the makefile in your build directory:

```
export REL_DIR=..
include $(REL_DIR)/Makefile.mk
```

Then, in your included makefile:

```
export VZW_BASE_DIR=$(PWD)/$(REL_DIR)
```

This limits the scope of changes you have to make to one location, the setting of `REL_DIR`. It then uses that variable to both reference the included file *and* set the base directory.

Comment: does not work though. It says*** Recursive variable `VZW_BASE_DIR' references itself (eventually).  Stop.

Comment: @Sarwan, check the update, that should get rid of the infinite recursion.

Comment: then I will not be needing to include Makefile.mk file.

Comment: @Sarwan, that's certainly an option. The fact is you _already_ have to know where the include directory is so you may as well make full use of that info.

Comment: Thanks @paxdiablo. I did exactly as you told.