# cmake and file paths in source code

Tags: c, file-io, cmake

How does one properly use file paths in source code (relative to the project root) when building with cmake?

**Details:**
I have a cmake project with basically this layout:

```
project
|-src/
| |-main.c
| |-CMakeLists.c
|-dat/
| |-foo.txt
|-build/
```

`main.c` basically contains a `main` function that tries to open a file, specified relative to the project's root directory, i.e., `dat/foo.txt`. When building with cmake, the binaries are located in `project/build/src`, which is also the working directory when running the program. `dat/foo.txt` is interpreted as `project/build/src/dat/foo.txt` which obviously is not available. One could replace the path in the source file with `../../dat/foo.txt`, which however is not at all a clean and nice solution.

This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950887/does-cmake-offer-a-method-to-set-the-working-directory-for-a-given-build-system) states that there is no easy way for setting the working directory of code executed by cmake (furthermore, the answer refers to a solution for Visual Studio, which I am not using).

What is the best practice for this problem?

Comment: How about using [`PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html) to set a preprocessor macro to the root project directory, and then use that macro inside your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736720/export-variable-in-makefile please see a similar problem here.

Comment: In my experience, a good practice in this case is to copy the data to the binary directory, preferably as a custom post-build step to account for changes in the source data. This at least makes it easier to relocate the binaries without caring about anything in the source directory.

Comment: @ComicSansMS +1. We had some default config files that I always copy to the output using this method. I do this with a custom target that calls "copy_if_different"